# Trying to verify date is within data range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to ensure that my user enters a valid date both format wise and for the given data set that I have. If the user enters an erroneous date, I want to prompt him or her to reenter a valid date. Then, once a valid date is entered I want to filter column A so just those dates show up.

I am currently getting a 1004 error with the current code that I have.

```
Sub date_entered_exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Not IsDate(date_entered) Then
        MsgBox "Input must be a date in the format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'"
        Cancel = True
    Else
        date_entered = Format(date_entered, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        If Not date_entered = Range("A").Find(what:=date_entered) Then
            MsgBox "Input a date within the range"
        Else
            WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=date_entered"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably have declared date_entered as string and as a result of that you are searching this string within dates and you get nothing.

Try converting it to date with CDate:

```
If Not CDate(date_entered) = Range("A").Find(what:=CDate(date_entered)) Then
```

**EDIT:**

This a lot different than your code but it should give you an idea how you can achieve this:

```
Sub date_entered_exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim date_entered As Date
    'date_entered = "13/07/2017"
    date_entered = Format(date_entered, "dd/mm/yyyy")

    If Not IsDate(date_entered) Then
        MsgBox "Input must be a date in the format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Rng = Range("A:A").Find(date_entered)

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Input a date within the range"
    Else
        WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=date_entered"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am still getting method range of object global failed on that line `If Not date_entered = Range("A").Find(what:=CDate(date_entered)) Then`

Comment: I was wildly guessing. Then I am currently unable to help you until you provide how you declare and get `date_entered`. You should provide the code related to this.

Comment: It is coming from a userform so I am going to guess that I can declare it either as a string or as a date. Which would be better? Edit: I used the code you provided and it does exactly what I'm looking for. I have two more questions. 1. If I want to change to mm/dd/yyyy, I just change it in the format and the prompt? 2. If I enter a date incorrectly and the correct it I get the prompt again (enter correct date) then it works. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Is date_entered a variable or textbox name?

Comment: It is a textbox name

Comment: You can assign it to a public variable which should be declared as date. Insert `Public datevar as Date` on top of everything out side of your subs in your module. Then use `datevar = Format(date_entered, "dd/mm/yyyy")` in your code. It is better you reference `date_entered` like `userform1.date_entered`

Comment: I have another question: I changed a line of code above because my date was not being passed, so now it reads `date_entered = Format(inv_list.date_entered, "mm/dd/yyyy")` I am now getting an object error on the following line: `WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=date_entered"` Thoughts?

Comment: Just apply my previous comment and it will be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149253/discussion-between-vba-n00b-and-tehscript).

Comment: So I need to do `Public datevar As Date` at the very top of my code then `datevar = Format(inv_list.date_entered, "mm/dd/yyyy")` and change all references from date_entered to datevar?

Comment: Yes. Also you should do these in a different module, not among userform's code. This is because when you close userform, you can still use your variable since you have it in a module.

Comment: Sorry to keep this going, but I am still struggling a bit with this. I did everything above but am now getting a type mismatch with the following line: `datevar = Format(inv_list.date_entered, "mm/dd/yyy")`

Comment: Simply try `datevar = inv_list.date_entered`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, but I've got a new issue. I will create a new topic rather than continuing the conversation here.